# How can I horizontally cross a row in DataGridView in C#?

Tags: c#, winforms

[image: screenshot]

I am new to `C#` and using `Windows Forms`.

As shown in the screenshot, does anyone know how I can horizontally cross (make cross line) for a selected row in a `DataGridView` when I click the cancel button?

I searched online but I did not get a solution.

```
private void ButtonCancel_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
}
```

Comment: you need to draw the line on the `DataGridView` using GDI+. Take a look at [this sample](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/8620/Drawing-and-Editing-Lines-with-GDI) - it is pretty old though. You just need to determine the starting point and the ending point of the line before drawing the line on the `DataGridView`.

Answer (score 5):

You can use the RowPostPaint event:

```
void dgv_RowPostPaint(object sender, DataGridViewRowPostPaintEventArgs e) {
  if (e.RowIndex == 1) {
    Rectangle r = e.RowBounds;
    e.Graphics.DrawLine(Pens.DarkRed, r.Left,
                                      r.Top + (r.Height / 2),
                                      r.Left + r.Width,
                                      r.Top + (r.Height / 2));
  }
}
```

Replace the index 1 with the row index you want to use for painting.

Comment: thank you for the help. this code works but not as I wanted, this code cross the row when I click on the row and I must use the even, what I want is: cross the selected  row on button click event, can you please tell me how can I modify this code?

Comment: @Kate Use a variable for the row index, set it in the button click event, then call `dgv.Invalidate();`

Answer (score 1):

You could change the back colour of each cell in the row which could possibly have the same effect

```
var row = dataGridView.Rows[rowIndex];
foreach(DataGridViewCell cell in row.Cells)
{
    cell.Style.BackColor = Color.Red;
}
```